# ''intent.getExtras().getString'' app crashes when reopen

Tags: java, android-studio

When I pass a variable from one activity to other everything works but
when I exit the app and reopen it, the app crashes.

I think is something with this line of code that take the variable from previous activity.

```
String codice = intent.getExtras().getString("idinput");
```

I tried to test with a fixed variable like this and the app doesn't crash.

```
String codice = "value";
```

This is the full code:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String codice = intent.getExtras().getString("idinput");

                Uri.Builder urlBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
                urlBuilder.scheme("http");
                urlBuilder.authority("myaddress");
                urlBuilder.appendEncodedPath("file.php");
                urlBuilder.appendQueryParameter("value", codice);
                URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.build().toString());

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String json;

                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString().trim();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Previous activity from where the variable is taken:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ControlloCodice.this, Visualizza.class);
            i.putExtra("idinput", inputname);
            startActivity(i);
```

SOLVED CHANGING THIS

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
                String codice = intent.getExtras().getString("idinput");
```

WITH THIS

```
String codice;
                try {
                    codice = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idinput");
                } catch (NullPointerException e ) {
                    codice = "";
                }
```

Comment: how does it crash, that's the exception in the logs?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

Comment: take a look at the stack trace and figure out where is the problem exactly, a unit test wouldn't hurt as well

Comment: but if I were to guess you mask the real exception with this `catch` and a `null` is returned and caused problem in another part of the program, this is not a good way to handle an exception, at least you should log the message, also catching the broad `Exception` is likely to cause problems

Comment: Thank you. solved. i update the answer with solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to check:

```
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    //use getString here
}
```